# How do I make "setup.py bdist_egg" to ignore specific source files?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to build a package for a django application, but excluding all tests modules.
I have tried setting

```
exclude = ["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]
```

on `find_packages` and defining a `MANIFEST.in`, but the tests are always compiled and included in the bundle.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I found the combination both adding [`find_packages`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) rule and writing out [`MANIFEST.in` rules](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) i.e. `prune tests`

Note that for python 3.2 and older you must have `__init__.py` in tests root, for `find_packages` command to consider tests folder to be a package.

Sample `find_packages` exclude command in `setup.py`

```
 packages=find_packages(
    exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
```

Sample `MANIFEST.in`

```
 include *.txt *.ini *.cfg *.rst
 recursive-include fmcc *.ico *.png *.css *.gif *.jpg *.pt *.txt *.mak *.mako *.js *.html *.xml
 prune tests
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I asked...did you try:

**find_packages(exclude=['tests'])**

Comment: I did. The `exclude` option only ignore packages(directories), not modules (tests.py).