# Is it possible to exclude certain files when building a wheel with setup.py?

Tags: python, setuptools

I know you can exclude certain packages using:

```
packages = find_packages("src", exclude=["test"]),
```

Is it also possible to exclude single python files?
I am building a binary wheel and want to exclude certain source files which I "cythonized" with a custom function:

```
python cythonize bdist_wheel
```

At the moment I remove all python files which also have a .so library file after building the wheel with a custom script and I would like to do that with setup.py.

Comment: There seems to be a bug-report on this, still open (Sept-2015): https://bitbucket.org/pypa/wheel/issues/99/cannot-exclude-directory

Answer (score 27):

There is a vague (IMO) article in py-docs ["How to include/exclude files to the package"](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute). **In two words**: use combination of [`find_packages`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) and [`MANIFEST.in`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/commandref.html#sdist-cmd)

*To check, what is in the package locally (before sending to PyPI), run `python setup.py sdist`, and then check the content of `./dist` folder (there should be tarball with your package).*

### My use-cases

#### Ignore one file

Add `MANIFEST.in` to the root of your package, and add these lines:

```
exclude .travis.yml
exclude appveyor.yml
exclude data/private/file.env
```

This files won't be included into distribution package.

#### Tests near sources

If in your project test files are placed near the code (in other words, there is no separated directory `tests`), something like this:

```
package1
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__test.py
│   ├── mymod.py
│   ├── mymod_test.py
│   ├── typeconv.py
│   └── typeconv_test.py
│
├── LICENSE
└── README.rst
```

You could add this lines to your `MANIFEST.in`, and `setuptools` will ignore test files:

```
global-exclude *_test.py
```

### See also

- [Exclude specific file // on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29978235/1115187)
- [Exclude submodule, include data // on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8556996/1115187)

Comment: `MANIFEST.in` works for source distributions, but it's ignored for wheels, which is what OP is asking about. See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/511.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [`exclude_package_data`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html?highlight=setup()#exclude-package-data) keyword from setup() function if you use `include_package_data=True`.

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name=...,
    ...,
    include_package_data=True,
    exclude_package_data={
        '': 'file_to_exclude_from_any_pkg.c',
        'pkg_name': 'file_to_exclude_from_pkg_name.c',
        ...
    }
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setuptools.find_packages()` along with a *revision-control plugin* i.e. `setuptools-git`.

Here is some extracts from a `setup.py` projects setup to exclude the `tests` directory:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name=...
    ...
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests"]),
    setup_requires=[
        'setuptools',
        'setuptools-git',
        'wheel',
    ]
```

Other plugins like the one used above are available for *bzr*, *darcs*, *monotone*, *mercurial*, etc.

**Tip:**

**Don't forget to clean your build directory by running**: `python setup.py clean --all bdist_wheel`

Comment: But the original question was `Is it possible to exclude single python files?` and you are talking about excluding a directory.

Comment: @Palasaty, could you add similar criticism to my answer))) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45847842/1115187

Comment: python setup.py clean --all

Comment: It's **so** infuriating that bdist_wheel behaves differently to sdist! This has prevented me from releasing wheels for my pure Python library because bdist_wheel would **always** include stuff that I'd manage to exclude from the sdist.

Comment: @CharlieClark what do you mean here?

Comment: If you use sdist, you can guarantee that the resulting package only contains what you've specified in setup and in the manifest. This is not necessarily the case with bdist_wheel.